# Using a shared ResourcePool for multiple Seize Blocks

Tags: anylogic

I have recently started using anylogic, and I am facing a problem with a shared ResourcePool in my process flow.

I want to create a process flow that consists of 10 tasks.
Each task is modeled by Seize-Delay-Release-Blocks and seizes either one operator and an additional (task-specific) tool or a machine. Each operator is capable of processing all tasks, so there is one shared ResourcePool *Operator*.

The problem I am facing is that although the capacity of the ResourcePool *Operator* is sufficiently high enough to be deployed on all tasks in parallel, the tasks are processed sequentially. For example, the model starts with processing all parts entering task 1; if the queue is empty, task 2 is processed, and so on. In case if new parts enter the queue of task 1, again, task1 is the only one being processed.
The Seize-Blocks lock the same as follows:
[Picture Seize-Block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjbfL.png).
It should seize one of the available Workers.

Using Task Priority in the Seize-Block with increasing priority per task (task 1 lowest -> task 10 highest) does not solve this problem as capacity remains unused because tasks are processed sequentially.

How do I have to set up the model that the shared ResourcePool *Operator* can be used for all tasks in parallel?

Comment: How did you define the Seize policies?

Comment: Thanks, Benjamin, for your reply! I've edited my question, including a picture of one of my seize blocks. I've not changed the standard settings so far. I had tried Unit with top rating in the Resource selection setting using 1-((Worker)(unit).getutilization(). Since the ResourcePool Worker is always seized together with another ResourcePool this leads to an Exception during runtime.

Comment: Currently, you require to have an operator *AND* a press at the same time. If this is the same for the other stations, that could explain it. Generally, I would go back step by step in your model dev to the point where things were as expected. Then, you know what causes the unexpected behavior and you can try to fix it. Too many variables in the mix currently :)

Comment: Yes exactly. It's always an operator AND another ResourcePool. I'll try it :)

Comment: well, then this could cause your observation, depends on how the other resources are set. I suggest you build the simple-most possible setup to test what you need and then implement

Comment: Thanks for the idea! In a simplified setup, seizing the resourcepools separately seems to be working.